# How to reverse tokenization after running tokens through name finder?

Tags: opennlp

After using NameFinderME to find the names in a series of tokens, I would like to reverse the tokenization and reconstruct the original text with the names that have been modified.  Is there a way I can reverse the tokenization operation in the exact way in which it was performed, so that the output is the exact structure as the input?

Example

> Hello my name is John. This is another sentence.

Find sentences

> Hello my name is John.
>   This is another sentence.

Tokenize sentences.

```
> Hello 
> my 
> name 
> is 
> John.
> 
> This 
> is 
> another 
> sentence.
```

My code that analyzes the tokens above looks something like this so far.

```
            TokenNameFinderModel model3 = new TokenNameFinderModel(modelIn3);
            NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(model3);

            List<Span[]> spans = new List<Span[]>();
            foreach (string sentence in sentences)
            {
                String[] tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence);

                Span[] nameSpans = nameFinder.find(tokens);
                string[] namedEntities = Span.spansToStrings(nameSpans, tokens);


                //I want to modify each of the named entities found
                //foreach(string s in namedEntities) { modifystring(s) };


                spans.Add(nameSpans);

            }
```

Desired output, perhaps masking the names that were found.

> Hello my name is XXXX. This is another sentence.

In the documentation, there is a link to this post describing how to use the detokenizer.  I don't understand how the operations array relates to the original tokenization (if at all)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENNLP-216

```
Create instance of SimpleTokenizer.
String sentence = "He said \"This is a test\".";
SimpleTokenizer instance = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;
Tokenize the sentence using tokenize(String str) method from SimpleTokenizer
String tokens[] = instance.tokenize(sentence);
The operations array must have the same number of operation name as tokens array. Basically array length should be equal.
Store the operation name N-times (tokens.length times) into operation array.
Operation operations[] = new Operation[tokens.length];
String oper = "MOVE_RIGHT"; // please refer above list for the list of operations
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) 
{ operations[i] = Operation.parse(oper); } 
System.out.println(operations.length); 
Here the operation array length will be equal to the tokens array length.
Now create an instance of DetokenizationDictionary by passing tokens and operations arrays to the constructor.
DetokenizationDictionary detokenizeDict = new DetokenizationDictionary(tokens, operations);
Pass DetokenizationDictionary instance to the DictionaryDetokenizer class to detokenize the tokens.
DictionaryDetokenizer dictDetokenize = new DictionaryDetokenizer(detokenizeDict);
DictionaryDetokenizer.detokenize requires two parameters. a). tokens array and b). split marker 
String st = dictDetokenize.detokenize(tokens, " ");
Output:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Detokenizer](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.9.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer.detokenizing).

`String text = detokenize(myTokens, null);`